# How to shift the column headers in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have .txt files I'm reading in with pandas and the header line starts with '~A'. I need to ignore the '~A' and have the next header correspond to the data in the first column. Thanks!

Comment: `pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=1)`?

Comment: That works to skip a whole row but I want to just skip the first label in the header row.

Comment: Please provide example of data you have and what you want accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("./test.txt", names=[ 'A', 'B' ], skiprows=1)    
print(data)
```

and the output for input:

```
~A, A, B
1, 2
3, 4
```

is:

```
c:\Temp\python>python test.py

   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

You have to name the columns yourself but given that your file seems to be malformed I guess it is not that bad.

If your header lines are not the same in all files, then you can just read them in Python:

```
import pandas as pd;

# read first line
with open("./test.txt") as myfile:
    headRow = next(myfile)

# read column names    
columns = [x.strip() for x in headRow.split(',')]

# process by pandas
data = pd.read_csv("./test.txt", names=columns[1:], skiprows=1)

print(data);
```

Comment: I am trying to do something similar, except my header row starts with ` # Time[s] Roll[deg]` , I would like to name my columns automatically using the header=0, but it is now taking # as one of the column header and putting the first dolumn data under it. Is there anyway I can delete the # from header and shift the data to Time[s] and Roll[deg] properly?