# how to shift names of pandas list on python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So what i tried to is to import a csv file using pandas but i did not get exactly what i want here is the code :

```py
cords = ["x1" , "y1" , .... , "x68" , "y68" ]
frame = pd.read_csv("hello.csv" , names = ["session" ] + cords , sep = ';')
frame
```

and here is a picture of the result ,
[shifted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJOz2.png)

NOTE : please click on Shifted Data to see the picture

well i want the 2 column to be the session and we can see that the y68 has literally nothing if we just shift the names one step to left everything would be great!
Can you please help me ?

Thank you and have a nice day !

Comment: Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659245/how-to-shift-the-column-headers-in-pandas

Comment: @GedasMiksenas Tbh i did not understand the answer in that page

Comment: @GedasMiksenas all i want is the first column where there is 2 everywhere to be the session so either shift all the data one step to right or shift the names one step to left

Comment: Add the first three lines of your csv file to the question, not an image.

Comment: If you want to shift the names of your columns, you can try `frame .columns = list(frame .columns[1:]) + list(frame .columns.values[0])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well using frame.columns after reading instead of names in the reading would solve the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).